# how to handle multiple request's response in ION and Volley

Tags: android, multithreading, android-volley, android-ion, ion-koush

i am working with instagram API in that i have use [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) lib for API request 
my question is how to handle multiple request's response using my code like this

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
   FutureCallback {
        :
        :
   Ion.with(context)
   .load("http://example.com/test1")
   .asString()
   .setCallback(this);

  Ion.with(context)
  .load("http://example.com/test2")
  .asString()
  .setCallback(this);

   @Override
   public void onCompleted(Exception exception, String response) {
    }

 }

//and i don't want to use like this (anonymous class )

  Ion.with(context)
  .load("http://example.com/thing.json")
  .asJsonObject()
  .setCallback(new FutureCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
      // do stuff with the result or error
    }
 });
```

in this case if i am requesting 2 request test1 and test2 how can i differentiate 2 request response in one callback

and Same thing with Volley also

### **EDIT**

any help on multi treading in android ?

[issue#635](https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/635)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a unique Id value for each of the request (the Key has to be the same) in the header and then in the response check for the same request ID. 
Note that you need to use "**.withResponse()**" and also implement "**FutureCallback< Response>**".

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
   FutureCallback<Response<String>> {
        :
        :
   Ion.with(context)
   .load("http://example.com/test1")
   .setHeader("REQUEST_ID","test1")
   .asString()
   .withResponse()
   .setCallback(this);

  Ion.with(context)
  .load("http://example.com/test2")
  .setHeader("REQUEST_ID","test2")
  .asString()
  .withResponse()
  .setCallback(this);

   @Override
   public void onCompleted(Exception exception, Response<String> response) {
         if (response.getRequest().getHeaders().get("REQUEST_ID").equals("test1")) {
             //do something based on response of test 1
         }else if (response.getRequest().getHeaders().get("REQUEST_ID").equals("test2")) {
             //do something based on response of test 2
         }
    }

 }
```

In the above example, you can make "REQUEST_ID" as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Context of any Class, Fragment or Activity in

1- .setCallBack(context)

After doing so, implement the FutureCallBack in the class, Fragment or Activity you provided the context.

After implementing the FutureCallBack it will declare the method onComplete() where you will be getting your response.